# Which friction acts on on a Rolling body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

First question is, is it static or kinetic friction which acts on the rolling body or both do?
Say we give a body (sphere lets say with radius $R$) with NO ANGULAR VELOCITY, just linear. Say we project it along +ve x. As the body  starts moving the friction opposes relative motion and acts along -ve x, this friction is kinetic as the body is slipping(right?)
Now this kinetic friction produces a torque in the clockwise sense and thus the angular velocity (say $w$) increases (in the clockwise direction) with time WHILE the linear speed decreases (right?).

So say after some time $t$, the value of velocity $v$ (which had been decreasing up until now) of body is **same** as the rotation velocity (which had been increasing up until now) of the body along the surface,i.e $v=wR$, Thus the point of contact with the surface doesn't have any net velocity and is essentially at east and thus NO FRICTION acts on it and it doesn't slip (right?) and we say the body is in pure roll.

Now the point of contact which is at rest is pushing against -ve x so STATIC FRICTION should act along +ve x (right?) and this static friction should now accelerate the linear speed and the pure rolling motion should break.
What am I missing?
Assuming there are no drag forces and the sphere is non=deformable.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't totally understand your last paragraph, but I think you are assuming there is a force acting in the plane of the table surface when there is rolling with no slip.  This is not true when the bodies are non-deformable.

The only forces between the ball and table would be the normal forces.

Imagine a situation with no gravity where the ball is "rolling" through space such that the bottom of the ball has zero velocity.  Now position a table under the ball such that they are just touching.  This is equivalent to the situation in your last paragraph, except with no normal force.

Answer (score 0):

> As the body starts moving the friction opposes relative motion and acts along -ve x, this friction is kinetic as the body is slipping(right?)

Correct.

> So say after some time $t$ the value of velocity $v$
> (which had been decreasing up until now) of body is same as the rotation velocity

Okay.

> Thus the point of contact with the surface doesn't have any net velocity...

I would prefer to say the point of the rolling object has the same velocity as the surface it's on.   In the frame where the surface is at rest, the point of contact is also at rest, yes.

> ... and is essentially at east and thus NO FRICTION acts on it

You can't go from "at rest" to "no friction".   Static friction *may* be present when there is no motion.   A box standing on level ground in a breeze is at rest, but there will be frictional forces to oppose the forces from the breeze.

> Now the point of contact which is at rest is pushing against -ve x so STATIC FRICTION should act along +ve x (right?)

That depends on the scenario.   In a pretend world with no drag, there is no friction because the velocity of the sphere and the rotation of the sphere aren't trying to separate.   It could roll onto a sheet of frictionless ice, but the contact point would still be at rest.

For a real sphere, there will be drag, so the velocity will decrease.   In that case static friction will act in the +ve x direction on the sphere.   This will simultaneously slow the rotation and it will reduce the deceleration from drag.

> and this static friction should now accelerate the linear speed

The force acts in that direction, but it will never be stronger than the drag, so it doesn't accelerate the object (just reduces the deceleration).  Without drag, there will be no friction.

Comment: I think i understand now after reading all the responses. In the absence of drag forces pure roll would continue indefinitely. Ig i missed the fact that for static friction to act some force hast to act on the object which is trying to moving it parallel to the surface, as only normal forces acts at pure roll the state wouldn't' change, so my last para is wrong. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have much of this right.

Two simple rules tell you how big the force of friction is to a good approximation. But the microscopic mechanism is complicated.

The first rule is static friction. When a rubber brick sitting on a table, static friction is the force that keeps it from sliding sideways. How big is the force? $0$. If the brick was sitting on a slope, how big would the force be? You could figure it out from the mass and angle. It would be just big enough to prevent motion. Static friction is always a force parallel to surfaces in contact that is just big enough to prevent motion.

Sometimes static friction is not strong enough to prevent sideways motion. If you push a brick sideways hard enough, the force will overcome static friction and the brick will move. When this happens, the character of friction changes. It is now dynamic friction, and a different rule describes it. Dynamic friction is a force parallel to two surface sliding over each other. The force is in a direction opposed to the motion. If you stop pushing, dynamic friction slows the brick to a stop. Friction becomes static again.

---

The ball starts out sliding. Dynamic friction exerts a sideways force that slows the bottom point and starts the ball rotating. Eventually the bottom point slows to match the speed of the surface it is rolling on. At this point, friction changes from dynamic to static.

When a ball is rolling, the point of contact is momentarily stationary. It does not slide. The acceleration is upward. That is a point approaches the bottom traveling straight down and slowing. It comes to rest for the instant at which it is in contact, and accelerates straight up. As soon as it gets away from contact, it begins to have a sideways component of velocity. But that is small at first.

For the instant the point is in contact, there is static friction. Static friction is a sideways force that is just strong enough to keep two surfaces from sliding. In this case, the force that is needed is $0$.

There are forces on a ball rolling on a horizontal surface. Gravity pulls it downward. The surface is rigid. That means it pushes back just hard enough to keep the ball from penetrating the surface. This normal force is perpendicular to the surface. The total force is $0$. The ball rolls at a uniform speed.

---